# Why is this average calculating incorrectly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

So I have two procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAnswersByPartner 
    @pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, -- partner id
    @sid INT -- survey id
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Sections.title AS section_title,
    Subsections.title AS subsection_title,
    Questions.id AS question_id,
    Questions.qtext AS question_text,
    Answers.val AS answer_val 
    FROM Partners
    INNER JOIN Questions ON 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN Subsections ON Subsections.id = Questions.subsection_id
    INNER JOIN Sections ON Sections.id = Subsections.section_id
    INNER JOIN Surveys ON Sections.survey_id = Surveys.id
    LEFT JOIN Answers ON Answers.partner_id = Partners.id
            AND Answers.question_id = Questions.id
    WHERE Partners.id = @pid AND Surveys.id=@sid
    ORDER BY Sections.id ASC
END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSectionAverages
    @partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @survey_id INT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT S.title, AVG(A.val)   
        FROM 
            Sections AS S INNER JOIN Subsections AS SS ON S.Id=SS.section_id
                          INNER JOIN Questions AS Q ON SS.section_id=Q.subsection_id
                          INNER JOIN Answers AS A ON A.question_id=Q.id
                          INNER JOIN Partners AS P ON A.partner_id=P.id
            WHERE S.survey_id=@survey_id AND P.id=@partner_id
            GROUP BY S.title
    END
```

and I can't figure out why the averages are calculating incorrectly.

For example, you can see in the screenshot below the result of `EXEC GetAnswersByPartner @pid='cd2c53e2-3bd4-451c-8451-6953b9cc7c8b', @sid=1;` in the section called `"Partner Growth"`

[image]

and that is calculating out to `100` as an average when I run

```
EXEC GetSectionAverages @partner_id='cd2c53e2-3bd4-451c-8451-6953b9cc7c8b', @survey_id=1;
```

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Your first query has a LEFT JOIN to the `Answers` table, while your second has an INNER JOIN. I'd suspect that the difference lies there. In other words, your second query may be excluding unanswered questions.

Comment: Yea, I figured that out right after I posted the question. Any idea how I can get the sections in the average to be ordered the same way as in the other query?

Comment: @SubparWebDev Use the same LEFT JOIN in both queries would seem to be the answer.